# Should I move to Seattle from Switzerland?

Tags: usa, relocation

My employer wants me to move from Zürich, Switzerland to Seattle. I have two small children and I'm worried that the USA will be substantially less child friendly than Switzerland. Also, I will incur a substantial pay cut by making the move. However, if I don't move, I won't be able to continue working on a project that I enjoy. I'm having terrible difficulty making a decision. What do people think about life in Seattle? Is it child friendly?

Comment: Is the project of sufficient importance and duration to warrant moving 8,500km? https://versus.com/en/seattle-vs-zurich and https://livingcost.org/cost/seattle/zurich